# Python 3 import module error: No module named request

Tags: python, geany, urllib3

Hello I am using python 3.4 on a Mac, Here is what I did-

```
import urllib.request
```

when I run the code it comes back with this error-

ImportError: No module named request

when I do pip3 freeze here are my modules-

```
pip3 freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
chardet2==2.0.3
html5lib==0.999999999
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.19.2
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.13.0
six==1.10.0
urllib3==1.20
webencodings==0.5.1
```

What could be the issue? thanks

Comment: Are you *certain* that this is in Python 3?

Comment: Try `import os;import urllib;print(os.path.realpath(urllib.__file__))` to make sure you are getting the right module.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.pyc
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.pyc
                                    This is what it printed:  I do also have python 2 installed, I do pip3 install for the urllib etc

Comment: So its a matter of how you are calling your script. `python` bad, `python3` good. `pip` bad. `pip3` good.

Comment: Guess I'm confused because in my script its under Versions/3.4/lib and also I have paranthesis around my print statements so not understanding how its running it in python 2, I am using the Geanie text editor, I just push f5 to run my scripts, Should I make a change to the path?

Comment: I don't know the OSX module structure. Is that a standard path for OSX? Is this a top-level script (you run it directly) or something that is imported by others? If a script, does it have a "shebang" (e.g., `#!/usr/bin/python`) on its first line? Which python you are using is determined by the the python used to execute the top level script.

Comment: In the geany "set build commands"  under "execute commands" it has python "%f" i changed it to python3 "%f" and now printed out python 3.4, looks like that was the issue, thanks!

Comment: You can have python print its version and search path with `python -c "import sys;print(sys.version);print(sys.path)"` - that one should be python 2 and your module path shouldn't be on it. `python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.version);print(sys.path)"` is python 3.

Comment: Okay, this was being run by another tool. That is useful information to included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the help of tdelaney.

Had to change the way my text editor was excecuting the code from "python '%f'" to "python3 '%f'", otherwise it was using python 2.